# exact functionality of the * wildcard in searchpatterns

Tags: c#, .net, wildcard

I have an folder with more than 150 files, I want to collect a list with all the ones which contain a certain keyword. The keyword can be at the beginning or somewhere in the middle. `"*.xml"` catches all the xml files.

Here is my question when I do this `"*partkey*.xml"` does this catch all the files which contain the substring? 
for example:
`string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("thepathtothefolder", "*key*.xml");`
Do I get my expected output?

Comment: Combination of Path.GetExtension(...) + string.Contains(...) will do the job

Comment: Read the ["Remarks"-section of `Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) and come back with a specific issue/question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look it up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx). There you will find the "exact" description of the meaning for the wildcard characters `*` and `?`. It is the same meaning the `*` caracter had since MS DOS times, it stands for 'zero or more' characters.

The line

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("thepathtothefolder", "*key*.xml");
```

will give you an array with all the filenames that contain thre characters 'key'.

Comment: Yes, finally a concrete value to the * :P
thanks for this, I tried googling the question but I couldn't really form the question appropriatly..

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd google is quite good at giving good matches, but i find reading the MSDN document for a method or class is often the fastest way to get the facts. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With search pattern `"*partkey*.xml"` you will get all the files that ends with ".xml" and contains string "partkey"

```
Output example:
123partkey123.xml
456partkey456.xml
```